# QtPlugins implementing multiple interfaces and casting to a common interface

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, shared-libraries

I have a set of interfaces that can be implemented by plug-ins in a Qt
application. Every plug-in must implement at least one common
interface, called `Base_plugin`, to provide some basics (description,
name, etc.). When calling a specific plug-in interface I often have to
get this basic to present it in the user interface. This leads to a
lot of code like:

```
Foo_plugin* p = getSuitableFooPlugin();
// cannot use qobject_cast, plug-in interfaces don't derive QObjects
Base_plugin* b = dynamic_cast<Foo_plugin*>(p);
setName(b->name());
p->getAction();
```

This works at least on gcc, but I'm afraid that this is not going to
work on Windows. Alternatively I could use `reinterpret_cast` or store
pointers of the correct type to each plug-in when loading them (I have
a valid `QObject*` there). Neither of those solutions seems really
clean to me.

Is there a better way around this problem?

Comment: If `Foo_plugin` inherits from `Base_plugin` then you don't need the `dynamic_cast` in this direction. Actually, since the base class provides the `name()` method, you don't even need to cast **at all**. Why don't you just write: `setName(p->name());` ?

Comment: @ereOn I would need virtual inheritance for that to work (there is `Foo_plugin`, `Bar_plugin` etc. and a plug-in can implement all of them at once). Does Qt support interfaces with virtual bases?

Comment: Not that familiar with Qt or gcc, but why would this code be different between gcc and Windows (I presume you mean VC++)?

Comment: As far as I know, Qt has nothing to do with inheritance. So yes, I see no reason why it wouldn't work. Moreover, it is a very common pattern to inherit from a class with virtual methods that acts as an interface.

Comment: @TomW Yes, I mean MSVC (edited). The behavior of `dynamic_cast` across module boundaries tends to be very erratic and I've been told that this should not work. Maybe I'm wrong. The code is still horrible.

Comment: @ereOn QObject has a severe impact on inheritance. It does not support e.g. multiple virtual inheritance.

Comment: @pmr: From the Qt documentation it seems it is not supported to inherit from `QObject` several times (or trough *virtual inheritance*) but I see nowhere that it can't be part of multiple inheritance (even if some of the classes have virtual methods). Where did you read that ?

Comment: @ereOn http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/plugins-howto.html#the-lower-level-api-extending-qt-applications The restrictions on interfaces are strange. I'll give it a try though.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you have smth like this (if you don't, think about refactor to make it like this)

```
struct IBase
{
    virtual QString name() const = 0;
    virtual void setName(const QString name&) = 0;
};
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(IBase, "best.app.ever.plugins.base");

struct IFoo
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};
Q_DECALRE_INTERFACE(IFoo, "best.app.ever.plugins.foo" );

struct Plugin: QObject, IBase, IFoo
{
    Q_OBJECT()
    Q_INTERFACES(IBase)
    Q_INTERFACES(IFoo);

    //....
};

Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2(best_app_ever, Plugin);
```

now when you load plugin, you get an `QObject` and you *shoud* use `qobject_cast` to cast this `QObject` to your interface classes.

Specializations of `qobject_cast` that process casting to your interfaces get created automatically by `Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE` macroses.

Comment: Yes, that's what I have and it is the boilerplate Qt example. _And_ it's the source of the problem which you don't address.

Comment: Read the question. I'm not satisfied with the way I have to cast to `IBase` all the time and there is a chance of it not working at all.

Comment: @pmr, why don't you derive interfaces one from other?

Comment: Read the discussion bellow the question.

Comment: @pmr, here a long descussion, why you cannot derive from `QObject` twice, but noting, why you cannot derive `Foo` from `Base`. You can even do virtual inheritance with those interfaces. You only cannot use virtual inheritance with `QObject`, (you might want derive from QObject and QWdiegt and you are not allowed, because QWidget inherited from QObject without virtual inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm not getting it right, but can't you just write:

```
Foo_plugin* p = getSuitableFooPlugin();
setName(p->name());
p->getAction();
```

Since `Foo_plugin` inherits from `Base_plugin`, and if `Base_plugin::name()` is public, you can call it without casting.

Comment: No, `Base_plugin` and `Foo_plugin` are both interfaces implemented by one plugin as in `Plugin : pulic QObject, public Foo_plugin, public Base_plugin`.

Comment: @pmr: I see. Perhaps the name `Base_plugin` is very misleading here as one might believe it is a *base* class for all `foo_plugin` classes.

Comment: Think `Base` as in `Basic` ;)